# View Pager same image

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager in a GridView , but when I cliked on one image , and if I have 8 images in gridview , will be in ViewPager same 8 images like the one I cliked , this is my code :

```
   public class ImageViewPager extends Activity {
// Declare Variable
int position;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set title for the ViewPager
    setTitle("ViewPager");
    // Get the view from view_pager.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);
    Intent in = getIntent();


    // Get the position
    int position = in.getExtras().getInt("position");

    // Get String arrays FilePathStrings
    String[] filepath = in.getStringArrayExtra("filepath");

    // Get String arrays FileNameStrings

    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event



    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this,this,filepath);
    List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    // Retrieve all the images
    for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        File file = new File(filepath[position]);
        Picasso.with(ImageViewPager.this).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        images.add(imageView);
    }

    // Set the images into ViewPager
    ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
    ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
    // Show images following the position
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
 }
```

ImagePagerAdapter class:

```
  public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<ImageView> images;

public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
    container.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView(images.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return view == o;
}
 }
```

Image Adapter:

```
  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private Activity activity;
public String[] filepath;

public ImageAdapter(Activity a,Context c,String[] fpath) {
    mContext = c;
    activity=a;
    filepath=fpath;
}

public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filepath[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


    // Set file name to the TextView followed by the position
    File file = new File(filepath[position]);
       Picasso.with(activity).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);

    return imageView;
}

// References to our images in res > drawable

}
```

And my OnCreate from MainActivity

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    delegate1 = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);

    //call the onCreate() of the AppCompatDelegate
    delegate1.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //use the delegate to inflate the layout
    delegate1.setContentView(R.layout.album_activity);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbarr);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nameAlbum2 = intent.getStringExtra("nameAlbum2");
    nameAlbum = intent.getStringExtra("nameAlbum");
    delegate1.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    delegate1.setTitle(nameAlbum2);

    Button btnChoosePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addimage);


    // Check for SD Card
    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } else {
        // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + nameAlbum);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listFile = file.listFiles();
            // Create a String array for FilePathStrings
            FilePathStrings = new String[listFile.length];
            // Create a String array for FileNameStrings
            FileNameStrings = new String[listFile.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                // Get the path of the image file
                FilePathStrings[i] = listFile[i].getAbsolutePath();
                // Get the name image file
                FileNameStrings[i] = listFile[i].getName();
            }
        }

        // Locate the GridView in gridview_main.xml
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        // Pass String arrays to LazyAdapter Class
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, FilePathStrings, FileNameStrings);
        // Set the LazyAdapter to the GridView
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Capture gridview item click
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(AlbumActivity.this, ImageViewPager.class);
                // Pass String arrays FilePathStrings
                i.putExtra("filepath", FilePathStrings);
                // Pass String arrays FileNameStrings
                i.putExtra("filename", FileNameStrings);
                // Pass click position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here in your ImageViewPager

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    File file = new File(filepath[position]);
    Picasso.with(ImageViewPager.this).load(file).placeholder(R.drawable.rtrt).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    images.add(imageView);
}
```

Replace

```
File file = new File(filepath[position]);
```

With

```
File file = new File(filepath[i]);
```